# Send form data to Google Spreadsheet from client side

Tags: html, forms, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have some form on my pure JS/HTML/CSS site (without server side). And have Google account. My purpose is send filled form from web client direct to Google Spreadsheet. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. I would do it by [creating an Apps Script](https://www.google.com/script/start/) and [deploying it as a web app](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#deploying_a_script_as_a_web_app). Here is a sample script: fill in the [Id of the spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyidid) and the name of one of its sheets.

```
function doPost(event) {
  var params = event.parameter;
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('..Id..').getSheetByName('..Name..');
  if (params.data !== undefined) { 
    sheet.getRange(1, 1).setValue(params.data);
    return ContentService.createTextOutput("Success");
  }
  else {
    return ContentService.createTextOutput("Oops");
  }  
}
```

Publish the script as a web app, allowing access to everyone (unless you want to deal with authentification). This will give you a URL such as `https://script.google.com/macros/s/..../exec`

On the client side, you send POST request to that URL. The script expects data to be in parameter "data".

```
var url = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/..../exec';
$.post(url, {data: 'hello world'});
```

(I'm using jQuery here just to have a shorter example; you can send a POST request in plain JavaScript.)

The cell A1 of the sheet you chose will have "hello world".

Comment: This is that I need. Thank you!

Comment: I've just get CORS problem. When I send POST request to foreign domain the browser restrict this. How to fix this?